# Building Trees and Extracting All Branches

Tags: vba

How should I break down the following problem into smaller parts?

Suppose I own a restaurant and want to design tonight's menu.

As a simple example, I have 3 types of ingredients:
Vegetables (tomatoes, potatoes, lettuce) 
Carbs      (Rice, pasta, bread)
Meat       (Pork, Chicken, Beef)

edit: In practice, there is an unknown amount of ingredients and ingredient types. 
I want to make a list of all dishes available. using the above example, each dish should have all 3 types of ingredients, e.g. tomatoes-rice-pork, tomatoes-pasta-chicken, potatoes-bread-beef.

In principle, my approach is to treat this as a tree, do a DFS. Create a branch object, as the tree is traversed, add each node to the branch object until the search reaches the tree's bottom, then create a new branch until every node is walked thru.     so it looks something like the below:

```
                                Meals
                    /             |                  \
               Tomatoes         Potatoes            Lettuce
            /     |   \        /   |   \           /   |    \
         Rice   Pasta  Bread   Rice Pasta Bread    Rice Pasta Bread
      /   |  \
     Beef Pork Chicken
```

Comment: Potatoes are a carb, not a vegetable :) but have you considered using XML to do this?

Comment: haha good call, thanks for the correction David, gotta brush up on my biology.

i know i should be using existing tools/libraries to do this. but for the sake of learning, i m eager to study how i can potentially implement this by myself.

Comment: You can traverse the options just by using a triple-nested `For` loop, over each of the menu components (veg, carb, meat). Results in 27 combinations. I would use the Microsoft XML, v6.0 library and build it as an xml document.

Comment: sure, though if my number of ingredient types or ingredients increase, i want the solution to be dynamic enough to handle them.

Comment: Well then you're talking about a more complicated problem, which would require *reading* inputs from some external source (how else would the application/code *know* which ingredients lists to use, etc.). It's not difficult per se, but it's outside the scope of your original question...

Comment: thanks again david, noted. just edited the question details.

Comment: So, do you have a specific question regarding a particular implementation or problem(s) implementing a specific approach? As your question is currently stated, it's basically a list of requirements: "I want it to do X, Y and Z and be dynamic so that it can handle more complicated scenarios".  You haven't attempted to solve any part of it on your own.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

This will list the combinations:

```
Const vegetables$ = "tomatoes,potatoes,lettuce"
Const carbs$ = "rice,pasta,bread"
Const meats$ = "pork,chicken,beef"

Dim v, c, m, i As Long

For Each v In Split(vegetables, ",")
    For Each c In Split(carbs, ",")
        For Each m In Split(meats, ",")
            Debug.Print v & "-" & c & "-" & m
        Next
    Next
Next
```

This will give you output like:

```
tomatoes-rice-pork
tomatoes-rice-chicken
tomatoes-rice-beef
tomatoes-pasta-pork
tomatoes-pasta-chicken
tomatoes-pasta-beef
tomatoes-bread-pork
tomatoes-bread-chicken
tomatoes-bread-beef
potatoes-rice-pork
potatoes-rice-chicken
potatoes-rice-beef
potatoes-pasta-pork
potatoes-pasta-chicken
potatoes-pasta-beef
potatoes-bread-pork
potatoes-bread-chicken
potatoes-bread-beef
lettuce-rice-pork
lettuce-rice-chicken
lettuce-rice-beef
lettuce-pasta-pork
lettuce-pasta-chicken
lettuce-pasta-beef
lettuce-bread-pork
lettuce-bread-chicken
lettuce-bread-beef
```

Ideally though I would use an XML library to build this out as an XML object, then you can easily write that to a file, etc.